# Light without any Light/Environnement with EEVEE

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I've a weird issue with EEVEE.

Just a simple scene with a cube no light of any kind, pure black environment no A/O but still the scene is lite ...

[image: Light Issue (EEVEE)]

The problem vanish when I use Cycles instead. As soon as I go back on EEVEE the issue is back.

[image: The same scene with Cycles]

If I open the defaut scene there is no problem at all. It comes from this specific file, can't understand the reason why.

Hope someone could help me to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same results when I tried to create an empty night scene without any light.

Even without any light in the scene, the "False Color" View Transforms showed that the polygons were lit in EEVEE... However, the render in Cycles was completely black.
I solved my issue by pressing "Bake Indirect Lighting" then "Delete Lighting Cache" and everything became black again in EEVEE and Cycles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer, very nice !
Now you tell me it seems so obvious ... shame on me :)